# Highcharts assign colors to series after using csvURL

Tags: highcharts

I'm importing a csv file using Highcharts cvsURL for a line chart. I'm using styledMode and I defined the default colors. Highcharts is using my stylesheet. Is there an easy way to tell each series which color to use?

I have lots of lines, so highcharts cycles through its 10 default colors. I need one of the colors to only be assigned to 2 specific series though.

Here is my code so far:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        styledMode: true //this totally separates the design from the svg.
    },
    data: {
        itemDelimiter: ',',
        csvURL: 'http://deq.at.utah.gov/wp-content/themes/deq/parts/charts/Ozone-4th-Highest-8hr-Front.csv'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ozone 4th Highest 8-hr Concentration Wasatch Front'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '(Ozone PPM)'
        }
    }
});
```

I think the API said something about assigning classes to a series. Maybe that would work because I could make custom CSS for only those series, but I can't see how to do that using csvURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `color` or `className` for series in this way:

```
data: {
  csvURL: '...'
},
series: [{
  color: '#00c735'
}, {
  color: '#c4392d'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kj9udgat/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.className

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color

Comment: This is excellent. I was hoping to use "styledMode: true", but I don't think styling a series like this works with that mode. Even if it did, I wouldn't know how to also apply matching styles to the legend. 

Using your className suggestion worked as expected and I could style the series however I wanted, but then it didn't match the legend.